# Duplicate file error at build time ionic EDIT

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

After installing a plugin, I'm getting the following error:

Execution failed for task ':transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/DEPENDENCIES
>           File1: C:\Users\Vinicius\Desktop\webapps\paypadapp\platforms\android\libs\httpcore-4.3.2.jar
>           File2: C:\Users\Vinicius\Desktop\webapps\paypadapp\platforms\android\libs\httpclient-4.3.3.jar
>           File3: C:\Users\Vinicius\Desktop\webapps\paypadapp\platforms\android\libs\httpmime-4.3.3.jar

When doing a search, I found the following solution

Add this in android manifest:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // will not include NOTICE file
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
    // as noted by @Vishnuvathsan you may also need to include
    // variations on the file name. It depends on your dependencies.
    // Some other common variations on notice and license file names
    exclude 'META-INF/notice'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
}
```

But where do I add that in ionic / cordova?

I created an ionic project from scratch and installed the plugin, the same error occurs

[image]